# git push to multiple repositories simultaneously

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

How can I make `git push` to push not only to `origin` but also another remote repository?

as `git push` is only an alias for `git push origin`, can I alias git push to push to 2 remote repositories at once (with just that one command)?

I’m not looking for a non-git script here but would like to set this up for my local repository in git.

When I tried it with post-push scripts I failed.

Comment: [would this serve your needs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Comment: interesting that it took almost 4 years to find the duplicate question/answers

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I don't think you can do it just by setting a flag on git, but you can modify a config file that will allow you to push to multiple remote repositories without manually typing them all in (well only typing them in the first time and not after)

In the `.git/config` file you can add multiple urls to a defined remote:

```
[remote "all"]
    url=ssh://user@server/repos/g0.git
    url=ssh://user@server/repos/g1.git
```

If you `git push all` now you push to all the remote urls.

Comment: The remote “hack” is probably what I was looking for. (It’s not redefining the `git push` -> `git push origin HEAD` alias but does the thing I want it to.) In `.git/config` once can add multiple `url`s to a `remote`. Thanks.

Comment: Something isn't working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273040/git-push-all-multiple-repositories-doesnt-work

Comment: What if the two repo has different password for same username (email)?

Comment: @MASh You can usually setup ssh keys to solve that issue.

Comment: That just asks me if I want to create a new branch on the remote with the name I am using for "all".

Comment: Does this push in parallel or sequentially ?

Answer (score 65):

### No manual editing

You can add multiple URLs to a remote branch (e.g. `all`) directly from command line by using `git config --add remote.xyz.url` with different URLs:

```bash
git config --add remote.all.url ssh://user@server/repos/g0.git
git config --add remote.all.url ssh://user@server/repos/g1.git
```

### Fully automatic

If you're *super lazy* and don't want to copy/paste URLs several times, this is for you:

```bash
function git-add-push-all() {
  while read -r name url method; do
    git config --add remote.all.url "$url"
  done < <(git remote -v | awk '!/^all/ && /push/')
}

git-add-push-all # from git (sub)directory
```

A full bashy script is possible (test `$name` and `$method`), but `awk` is sweet and there is love for everyone.

### Push

Then you can push to all remote with

```
git push all
```

### References

- [git-config(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I just set this up and it is probably worth noting that I needed to leave out the ssh:// in the urls (I'm using bitbucket and bluehost) so my git config command looked like this: git config --add remote.all.url user@server/repos/g0.git

Comment: additional info: the first `git config -add` will create a fetch & push remote, while the subsequent `git config -add` will only create a push remote.

Comment: I'm sorry, how Windows users may use your automatic script? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных try [Bash on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez: I have Windows 10 LTSB, at the moment Bash on Windows [**don't support LTSB**](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1281). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get url from configured remotes :

```
for repo in g0 g1 ...
do
    git config --add remote.all.url `git config remote.$repo.url`
done
```

where g0, g1, ... are the names of your remotes.