# Adding a Git remote... am I doing it right?

Tags: git

When I merged a topic branch into master I received this message. I also have a remote at bitbucket named origin and heroku is named dev (originally origin, but renamed).

Should I also have something saying how many commits behind origin/bitbucket is? Is this because the bitbucket (now origin) was not cloned? I suspect it has something to do with tracking branches but i'm not entirely sure what that means.

```
 mistakes|tags-2col ⇒ co master
 Switched to branch 'master'
 mistakes|master ⇒ gmerge tags-2col 
 Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
  app.rb                 |    2 ++
  views/new/all_tags.erb |   57 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------
  2 files changed, 41 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)
 mistakes|master ⇒ gs
 # On branch master
 # Your branch is ahead of 'dev/master' by 2 commits.
 #
 nothing to commit (working directory clean)


 mistakes|master ⇒ git remote
 dev
 origin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only see a message regarding `master` compared to its [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) branch.

If `master` is tracking '`dev/master`', then you know how it stands compared to that remote branch.
See "[Git: which is the default configured remote for branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847101/git-which-is-the-default-configured-remote-for-branch)".

You *could* setup a remote with *multiple* urls, but it doesn't seem safe:
See "[Git status in regards to multiple remote repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684637/git-status-in-regards-to-multiple-remote-repositories)".

Comment: Thanks!! much appreciated, I just switched tracking to Origin.. I think i'm squared away now.