# Link Heroku app to Github repo. For what?

Tags: heroku, github

Recently I saw this field in my heroku application settings.

> Link your app to a GitHub repository to see commit diffs in the activity log.

I tried to add 'myusername/myrepo' in this field, but it didn't change anything in activity log. How can I use this setting? And for what?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's subtle, but your activity log has changed. When you add a repository in Heroku settings, the commit hashes in your activity log turn into links to GitHub, like so:

[image]

Comment: I am having a problem finding this in heroku's new UI, anyone find it?

Comment: Things are moved around a little, but the commit hash is still right there in the message. For that repository the message reads "Deployed c656f71", and the commit hash is clickable.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to see your code in Github you must add Github as a remote repository

```
git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/repo.git
git remote set-url --add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Every time you push your commits they will push to both heroku and github

```
git push origin
```

Now when you click on the commit links, they will take you to github.

Comment: Strangely it doesn't work, unless I do it in the UI and save the changes, so from the cli ( Gitbash ) it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, I rarely use the Github UI, I always push from the command line and it seems to work for me. What error does it give you?

Comment: I got it working on my Windows machine, but on my OSX one it keeps saying that I have invalid credentials. But if I try with a ssh link, it works.

Comment: Additionlly to this, add both remotes to a single name like "all" in your .git/config file so you dont have to push twice each time. see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255865/git-push-to-multiple-repositories-simultaneously