# git with app in heroku and github

Tags: heroku, github

With an app in heroku, with git url like `git@heroku.com:app.git`,
And a repo in github https://github.com/username/other_app.git

Is possible sync the two repos for hosting the sema app in two git servers (heroku and github) ?

And also  [Link Heroku app to Github repo. For what?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12708716/430059)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course this is possible, because git is a [distributed repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows). You can configure multiple remotes, one at GitHub and one at heroku, and just push your changes to both of them.

Example:

1. [Create repository at GitHub](https://github.com/new)
2. Clone this repository on your machine, now you have setup the remote "origin" to be GitHub
3. Setup heroku and add the heroku git remote (either by running `heroku create` or `heroku git:remote -a my_heroku_app`). Find details in the [git documentation of heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Answer (score 0):

here are some useful commands when working with github/heroku:

show github remote:

git remote show origin

show heroku git:

git remote show heroku

push github to heroku:

git push heroku master

if you have a 'staging' branch on github and want to push this to heroku git (master) for a 
'staging app':

git push heroku staging:master -v