# git push to different branches on multiple remotes

Tags: git, branch, push

I have a local repository that i want to push to multiple remote repositories (`firstremote`, `secondremote`).
This can simply be done by editing `.git/config` and creating a new `remote` with multiple `url`s.

But additionally I want to push my local branch to different-named remote branches. E.g. push (`mybranch`) to a branch named `firstbranch` on `firstremote` and to `secondbranch` on `secondremote`.

For this I have no idea how to specify the different upstream branch names.

Note: I'd like to do the push automatically with a single `git push`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch?rq=1

Comment: I know how to use it for a single upstream, but not how to set multiple for same branch

Comment: Just make an alias that pushes to multiple remotes.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best hint so far. Added alias `push-all = !git push firstremote mybranch:firstbranch && git push secondremote mybranch:secondbranch` to projects git config. So I also used @mahead's one-liner ;).

Answer (score 3):

Use colons! As per [git-push doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> The format of a  parameter is an optional plus +, followed by
> the **source ref , followed by a colon :, followed by the
> destination ref .** It is used to specify with what  object
> the  ref in the remote repository is to be updated. If not
> specified, the behavior of the command is controlled by the
> push.default configuration variable.
>
> The  is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but
> it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as master~4 or HEAD
> (see gitrevisions(7)).
>
> The  tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this
> push. Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be
> named. If : is omitted, the same ref as  will be updated.

So, this should do the trick:

```
git push firstremote mybranch:firstbranch
git push secodremote mybranch:secondbranch
```

Comment: Yes, I know this syntax. Maybe I didn't mention that explicitly but I would prefer to use a single push command with as less options as possible to simplify work flow. Isn't that possible?

Comment: One push is for one remote. [A remote can have multiple URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255934/750510), thus you can push to multiple urls with one command, but it does not solve the problem of naming the branches and IMHO this is not worth the trouble.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned in my question. Then I have to do it manually or write a 2-liner ;) Thanks so far

Comment: You can write it in one line! `git push firstremote mybranch:firstbranch && git push secodremote mybranch:secondbranch`