# Visual Studio git-push to two repositories

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I want to start a new project (VS 2013) and I want to work with a TFS 2013 Git repo for source control, bug tracking, team room and so on.
But I have the requirement from my management to push the source code also to a different git repo (No TFS).

Do you have an idea how to push my changes automaticly to the TFS Git Project and the second Git repo?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try and define a remote named "all", as in "[git push to multiple repositories simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255934/6309)", and see how Visual Studio 2013 runs a push to that remote.

The idea is to include all the remote url you want to push to in the remote definition:

```
[remote "all"]
    url=/url/repo1
    url=/url/repo2
```

You can do that by directly editing your `.git/config` file within your local repo.

Comment: This didn't work for me using VS2017. Got an error claiming branch master doesn't exist. Pushing individually to each one still worked fine though.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption Was it because the remote repo did not have a master branch (was empty)?

Comment: both remote repos had identical none-empty master branches.

Comment: @VonC VS only pushes to origin. Even if I delete origin, it throws error

Comment: @Natiq Then you can try and add URLs to the remote origin section of your `.git/config`