# Xcode 6.2 won't load remote git repos

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, bitbucket

I need to keep my Xcode project in 2 remote repos. Below are the steps I took.

1. Created an empty folder in my Mac.
2. Added a .gitignore file.
3. Created a project using Xcode 6.2.
4. Created a repo on Bitbucket.
5. Created a repo on Github.
6. By Selecting Source Control -> Working Copies -> Configure -> Add Remote, I added two remotes.
   [image]
7. Then by selecting Xcode Preferences -> Accounts, I filled up the user credentials for each account.

Then I went to commit the initial changes of my project by selecting Source Control -> Commit, it keeps showing *Loading remotes...* in the remote selection drop down but it wouldn't load.

[image]

Am I missing something here? Any steps I missed? I also tried adding them individually to see if it's something with one of the remotes but that didn't work for both of them either.

I opened the git config file on TextEdit and this is what I have there.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "bitbucket"]
    url = https://Isuru-Nanayakkara@bitbucket.org/Isuru-Nanayakkara/coolproject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bitbucket/*
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/CoolProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: You could try and declare both remote under one name, to see if that works better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637593/6309.

Comment: @VonC Hi, thanks for the response. I tried it but that didn't work either. Although I was able to resolve my issue in a different way. I posted it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29041553/1077789).

Answer (score 4):

I was on a **detached head** (a commit made by another developer) hence there was no matching commit on my branches from my repo. As a result I was getting this:

[image]

How I got myself into a detached head? Simply put I did something like `git checkout c10847ae6708fadc73d451a68e2dsdf30dbbabd86`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after some fiddling I was able to get it working. Again here are the steps I took.

1. First I committed my changes locally. I did this through Xcode.
2. Since the remotes weren't showing in Xcode, I turned to the Terminal's aid. First I pushed to Bitbucket's repo. Initially I tried with `git push bitbucket` but that would give me an error. Upon searching I found out that I need to set a default remote for my local repo. So I ran the following command and the changes were pushed to the Bitbucket's repo successfully.

   `git push --set-upstream bitbucket master`
3. Then when I tried to push to the github with `git push github`, I got this new error **![rejected] master -> master (fetch first)**. Even after pulling the latest from Bitbucket, I'd still get this error. So in the end to get past this, I ran the following command and force pushed the repo to Github as well.

   `git push -f github master`
4. After that now I can do my changes in Xcode and push to both remotes from Xcode itself. Now the remotes appear in the drop down! Maybe this is an Xcode bug(?).

**Note:** If the steps I took are wrong or if there is a cleaner or more right way to go about this, please post your answer. I'm still very much open for suggestions.

Comment: That would explain the "loading" issue: the GitHub repo wasn't compatible (because it had already an history of its own and wasn't really empty).