# Simultaneously update IBM Bluemix git repo and personal Github repo

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud

I have a personal web project I am working on and I've decided to deploy it as a IBM Bluemix Application. It turns out they have their own git control and to facilitate deployment, it feels like it would be easier to continue building on the Bluemix git stream. The problem with that then is my personal Github repo will not reflect any realtime changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the answer to this question?

[git push to multiple repositories simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255865/git-push-to-multiple-repositories-simultaneously)

basically you can edit the `.git/config` file to add multiple repositories to a single remote so when you do a git push it will push to all the defined repositories.

Also you could do the same using the command described in one of the answers in the link above: `git config --add remote.xyz.url` then `git push xyz`